# How to compare varbinary data type in where clause

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

I have a linked server that is created to pull user details from a specific Organisation Unit with a scheduled sql job agent.

The table is created to hold user details has a column for ObjectGUID number and the type is defined as varbinary(50) (I am not sure why..).

The process checks if there is a new user by comparing the ObjectGUID number the saved Users table and if there is a new number then insert the new user in the table.

However I have noticed that the comparisons actually not really working properly.

```
SELECT 
tbl.objectGUID AS UserGUID 
FROM [dbo].[ActiveDirectoryUsers] tbl
WHERE tbl.objectGUID NOT IN (SELECT UserGUID FROM dbo.Users)
```

When I create a new user the new user is appearing in the ActiveDirectoryUsers view.

but when the where clause added to compare results with Users table then result is always empty. It looks like I need to cast or convert the varbinary to varchar then do the comparisons. I tried to cast the varbinary into varchar and uniqueidentifier but still it does not work.

Any idea how would I do the comparisons?

> Update

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ActiveDirectoryUsers] AS 
SELECT "SAMAccountName" AS sAMAccountName, "mail" AS Email,
  "objectGUID" AS objectGUID
   FROM OpenQuery(ADSI, 'SELECT SAMAccountName, mail, objectGUID
               FROM   ''ldapconnectionstring.com''')
```

An example of objectGUID in the Users table

> 0x1DBCC071C69C8242B4895D42750969B1

Comment: Please update your question with the fields and their type. What is varbinary(50), dbo.Users.UserGUID? Or [dbo].[ActiveDirectoryUsers].objectGUID? Od both?

Comment: If `dbo.ActiveDirectoryUsers.objectGUID` is `varbinary(50)`, is `dbo.Users.UserGUID` too? Or is it the string representation of a GUID?

Comment: ActiveDirectoryUsers.objectGUID is not deifned. It is a view. I added the view creation  script. But when I look at the view under columns in Sql management studio I can see that type of objectGUID is varbinary(4000).

Comment: So one field id varbinary(50) and other varbinary(4000)? And where is varchar?

Comment: @sepupic there is no varchar. I am just asking how to get the query working. When I do comparisons between varbinary the result is wrong. Even though the objectGuid is not in Users table the result do not show that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not cast `varbinary` to smth particular to be able to use it in `WHERE` clause.
Your problem is that you use `NOT IN` where `NULL` values are present.

Try to execute my code first as it is (it will return 1 row) and then uncomment `NULL` value insert and execute it again.
This time you'll get 0 rows:

```
 declare @t1 table (guid varbinary(50))
 insert into @t1
 values(0x1DBCC071C69C8242B4895D42750969B1)--, (null);

 declare @t2 table (guid varbinary(50))
 insert into @t2
 values(0x1DBCC071C69C8242B4895D42750969B1), (0x1DBCC071C69C8242B4895D42750969B2);

 select *
 from @t2 t2
 where t2.guid not in (select guid from @t1);
```

To fix your problem, try to use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN` like this:

```
 select *
 from @t2 t2
 where not exists (select * 
                   from @t1 t1
                   where t1.guid = t2.guid);
```

In your case the code should be like this:

```
SELECT tbl.objectGUID AS UserGUID 
FROM [dbo].[ActiveDirectoryUsers] tbl
WHERE not exists (SELECT * 
                  FROM dbo.Users u
                  where u.UserGUID = tbl.objectGUID );
```

Comment: checking for null fixes the issue. Is there any difference between checking for null or using your solution not exists?

Comment: Maybe there was a differnce ages ago but now the server is smart enough to produce the same execution plan for both cases, so it's perfectly aware of what it is asked for. Maybe NOT EXISTS is more intuitive in sense it corresponds to English description of what you want